# node.js handling pipe result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using the [Inbox](https://github.com/andris9/inbox) module for node to process incoming mail with the following function call:

```
client.listMessages(-1, function(err, messages){
    messages.forEach(function(message){
        client.createMessageStream(message.UID)
              .pipe(process.stdout, {end: false});
    });
 });
```

This logs the mail to console with 'process.stdout', however I want to save the result to mongo, or do other javascript stuff, how can i do it?

Comment: I take it you're not asking about mongoose/saving to DB - are you asking how to get hold of the message outside the function?

Comment: Making function which saves data into mongoDB and throw message to that in the callback function. is that so hard?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that [createMessageStream](https://github.com/andris9/inbox#fetch-message-contents) is returning a [stream interface](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) object. The methods to access the data are shown in that link.

As saving the data into MongoDB there is the [basic driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) or modules such as [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) that can provide you with methods to do this.